# Получаю ошибку 1054 при попытке добавления записи в таблицу (MySQL Workbench)

Tags: mysql, insert

Есть таблица user, в ней много полей, но NOT NULL и без default value только 3 (login, password, email). Все три типа varchar.
Пытаюсь добавить запись запросом:
INSERT INTO user (login, password, email) VALUES ('Den', '12345', 'test@mail.ru');
получаю:
Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'login' in 'field list'
Поле существует, называется 'login'. При изменении запроса на:
INSERT INTO user (password, email) VALUES ('12345', 'test@mail.ru');
получаю (логично):
Error Code: 1364. Field ' login' doesn't have a default value
Все происходит в MySQL Workbench.
Не понимаю в чем проблема, если поле существует и название пишу правильно

Comment: *таблица user, в ней много полей* Неважно - показывайте полный вывод SHOW CREATE TABLE. *получаю: Error Code: 1054. ... Error Code: 1364.* Проверяйте наличие SELECT и INSERT privilege на это поле. А также проверьте наличие и, если есть, валидность триггеров.

Answer (score 0):

to Akina
'CREATE TABLE `user` (
`id` bigint unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT ''Первичный ключ'',
`login` varchar(15) NOT NULL COMMENT ''Логин пользователя'',
`password` varchar(100) NOT NULL COMMENT ''Пароль пользователя'',
`email` varchar(25) NOT NULL DEFAULT '''' COMMENT ''Электронная почта пользователя'',
`phone` varchar(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '''' COMMENT ''Телефон пользователя'',
`address` varchar(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT '''' COMMENT ''Адрес пользователя'',
`birth_date` date NOT NULL DEFAULT ''1970-01-01'' COMMENT ''Дата рождения пользователя'',
`registration_date` date NOT NULL DEFAULT ''1970-01-01'' COMMENT ''Дата регистрации пользователя'',
`is_admin` tinyint NOT NULL DEFAULT ''0'' COMMENT ''Роль пользователя. True(1) - администратор, False(0) - клиент.'',
`is_banned` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT ''0'',
`user_status_id` tinyint unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT ''1'',
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
UNIQUE KEY  `login_UNIQUE` (`login`),
UNIQUE KEY `email_UNIQUE` (`email`),
UNIQUE KEY `phone_UNIQUE` (`phone`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=6 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci COMMENT=''Таблица пользователей'''

Триггеров нет